# Append in host_vars to list from group_vars/defaults

Tags: ansible

Suppose I have a list configured in the role defaults (under `roles/myrole/defaults/main.yml`):

```
the_list:
  - one
  - two
```

And suppose that for a particular host I need to add also `three` to the list. Is it possible?

By default, the list is overriden, rather than concatenated. E.g. if I put into host_vars:

```
the_list:
  - three
```

... then the resulting list will include just `three`, the other two elements will be lost.

Any way to merge the lists? Maybe with some kind of yaml / jinja magic...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a number of issues and feature requests raised around this on the Ansible GitHub; see [this pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/25948) for example. In summary, there isn't a good way to do this yet, hopefully there will be soon.

A common workaround for the time being is to define a list `values` in one place and a second list `extra_values` elsewhere then merge them before use.